# Calculate end dateTime(ISO format) from start dateTime(ISO format) and duration(hh:mm format)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Let,

**startDateTime** => `2019-05-18T11:40:00-07:00`

**timeZone** => `-07:00`

**duration** => `23:10`

**durationHrs** => `23`

**durationMin** => `10`

**endDateTime** => ?? (be in same format as of `startDateTime`)

So far, I tried as below :

```
const endMs = (+new Date(startDateTime)) + (((durationHrs)*60*60+(durationMin)*60)*1000);
const endDateTime = `${new Date(endMs).toISOString().split('.')[0]}${timeZone}`;
console.log(endDateTime);
```

Please, take care of **time zone**. Thnaks in advance !!

Comment: Yes, I tried. Let me send u

Comment: please, see the update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again and finally got a solution using javascript and momentjs by playing with milliseconds.

```
const st = '2019-05-18T11:40:00-07:00';

const tz = '-07:00'

const dur = '23:10';

const hr = 23;

const mn = 10;


const convert = (num) => num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
const hrs = hr * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const mins = mn * 60 * 1000;
const getms = new Date(`${st.split('-')[0]}:00`).getTime();
const totalMs = getms + hrs + mins;

const year = new Date(totalMs).getFullYear();
const month = convert(new Date(totalMs).getMonth()+1);
const date = convert(new Date(totalMs).getDate());

const getHrs = convert(new Date(totalMs).getHours());
const getMin = convert(new Date(totalMs).getMinutes());

const getendTime = `${year}-${month}-${date} ${getHrs}:${getMin}:00`;


const momentend = moment.tz(getendTime, moment.tz.guess()).clone().tz(this.$data.selectedZone.split('$')[1]).format();

console.log(momentend);
```